# Convert multiple relationships between 2 nodes to a single one with weight

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have the following graph, describing co-occurrence of car brands in documents:

```
CREATE 
  (`0` :Car {value:"Ford"})
, (`1` :Car {value:"Subaru"})
, (`2` :Car {value:"VW"})
, (`0`)-[:`DOCUMENT` {value:"DOC-1"}]->(`1`)
, (`0`)-[:`DOCUMENT` {value:"DOC-2"}]->(`1`)
, (`1`)-[:`DOCUMENT` {value:"DOC-3"}]->(`2`);
```

[image: source graph]

If there are many relationships between two nodes - for the purpose of visualization - I want to replace it with a single one and calculate the weight:

```
VW ---1--- Subaru ---2--- Ford
```

How can this be achieved?

I tried the following query:

```
MATCH (n1)-[r1:DOCUMENT]-(n2)
RETURN n1, n2, apoc.create.vRelationship(n1, 'WEIGHT', {weight:count(r1)}, n2);
```

but this is **not** the expected result:

[image: query graph - wrong result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the relationship direction is not specified in `MATCH (n1)-[r1:DOCUMENT]-(n2) RETURN *;`, every relationship is returned **twice**:

```
╒══════════════════╤══════════════════╤═════════════════╕
│"n1"              │"n2"              │"r1"             │
╞══════════════════╪══════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│{"value":"Ford"}  │{"value":"Subaru"}│{"value":"DOC-1"}│
├──────────────────┼──────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│{"value":"Ford"}  │{"value":"Subaru"}│{"value":"DOC-2"}│
├──────────────────┼──────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│{"value":"Subaru"}│{"value":"Ford"}  │{"value":"DOC-1"}│
├──────────────────┼──────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│{"value":"Subaru"}│{"value":"Ford"}  │{"value":"DOC-2"}│
├──────────────────┼──────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│{"value":"Subaru"}│{"value":"VW"}    │{"value":"DOC-3"}│
├──────────────────┼──────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│{"value":"VW"}    │{"value":"Subaru"}│{"value":"DOC-3"}│
└──────────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

Specify the direction by changing the `MATCH` clause to either `MATCH (n1)-[r1:DOCUMENT]->(n2)` or `MATCH (n1)<-[r1:DOCUMENT]-(n2)`. The remaining part of the query is correct.